# Unable To Associate Automated Tests with Test Cases

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests

I'm automating tests by means of CodedUI in VS2015 Enterprice(.NET4.7.2) and running them from Azure DevOps. I need to associate manual test with automated test case via Work Item, but I don't see my test case (checked into tfs) in "Automated test name"-List (but older tests are listed.) Even so this test case runs succesfully in Azure Pipeline with "Automation State"= planned. Why can test case not be listed in "Automated test name"  and how can I add it and change "automation state" to automated? Thanks

Comment: Hi Nati A Chramm, any update on this? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 3):

The process to associate an automated test with a test case is:

1. Create a test project containing your automated test.
2. Check your test project into an Azure DevOps or Team Foundation
   Server (TFS) repository.
3. Create a build pipeline for your project, ensuring that it contains
   the automated test.
4. **Use Visual Studio Enterprise or Professional 2017** or a later version
   to associate the automated test with a test case as shown below. The
   test case must have been added to a test plan that uses the build
   you just defined.

---

**Q: What types of tests are supported?**

A: These are the limitations for each type of test:

- Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1
  of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.
- Tests that use **MSTest v2**, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be
  associated with a test case workitem when using **Visual Studio 15.9
  Preview 2 or later**. However, these tests cannot be run using
  Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.

More details please kindly refer our official doc: [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)

If you are unable to see the Automated Option in the dropdown there are only 2 options available in the dropdown - 'Not Automated' and `Planned`.

This is caused you didn't associate automated tests successfully. To display the `Automated` option, you need to Associate automated tests with test cases.

Take a look at this similar issue: ['Automated' option not shown in 'Automation Status' dropdown in Testcase work Item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/513436/automated-option-not-shown-in-automation-status-dr.html)